# Find "Material", copy it's cells and paste into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am a bit new in VBA. What I'm trying to do is to find word "Material" in a row (n), copy all it's cell from above and paste them into another sheet in column A. arr2 - are columns that will use the same function but with different words.
From my code, I keep receiving error. Could you please help me fix the code ?

```
Dim t As Range
    n = InputBox("Row number of FIRST MATERIAL")
    arr2 = Array("A", "D", "E", "O", "P", "S", "W", "Y", "AB")
    Set t = Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning").Rows(n).Find("*Material*", LookAt:=xlWhole)
       If t Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Material was not found")
      End If

       If Not t Is Nothing Then
      Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning").Rows(n).Find("*Material*", LookAt:=xlWhole).End(xlDown).Copy
        Sheets("GCC1").Column("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       End If
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? and what is the error?

Comment: Why do you make an array and not reference it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following:

With this line:

```
Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning").Rows(n).Find("*Material*", _
LookAt:=xlWhole).End(xlDown).Copy
```

You copy the last cell in the given sheet. E.g. cell on row `1048576` Or the lower cell, from the found one. But you copy only one cell.
Then with the next line

```
Sheets("GCC1").Column("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

You try to paste this cell into a column. That's not gonna happen.

---

In general, try to rewrite your code into something, that anyone can easily reproduce. Then the errors would be more visible. Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim n               As Long
    Dim t               As Range
    Dim arr2            As Variant
    Dim strToLookFor    As String: strToLookFor = "*Material*"

    n = 11 'you do not need an input box for testing purposes

    'How do you use this array?
    arr2 = Array("A", "D", "E", "O", "P", "S", "W", "Y", "AB")

    Set t = Worksheets(1).Rows(n).Find(strToLookFor, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If t Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print ("Material was not found") 'No msgbox when testing
    End If

    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        'you copy only one cell here
        Worksheets(3).Rows(n).Find(strToLookFor, LookAt:=xlWhole).End(xlDown).Copy

        'but you try to paste it in a column?
        Worksheets(4).Column("A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub testso1()

Dim t As Range
    n = InputBox("Row number of FIRST MATERIAL")
    arr2 = Array("A", "D", "E", "O", "P", "S", "W", "Y", "AB")
    Set t = Sheets("Project Parts Requisitioning").Rows(n).Find("*Material*", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("GCC1").Columns("A") = t.EntireColumn.Value
    Else
        MsgBox ("Material was not found")
    End If

End Sub
```